# query-based routing of sibling views in ui-router

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

Suppose my app has two sides: "left" and "right". Each side has tabs. The URL which governs the application looks like this:

```
app/splitscreen/?leftTab=1&rightTab=1
```

So far I have the following HTML template:

```
<!-- splitscreen.tpl.html -->

<!-- left side -->
<a ui-sref="splitscreen({leftTab: 1})">Left tab 1</a>
<a ui-sref="splitscreen({leftTab: 2})">Left tab 2</a>

<div ui-view="left"></div>

<!-- right side -->
<a ui-sref="splitscreen({rightTab: 1})">Right tab 1</a>
<a ui-sref="splitscreen({rightTab: 2})">Right tab 2</a>

<div ui-view="right"></div>
```

And here's my state:

```
$stateProvider.state('splitscreen', {
    url: '/splitscreen?leftTab&rightTab',
    views: {
        'app': {
            templateUrl: 'splitscreen.tpl.html'
        },
        'left@splitscreen': {
            template: 'I\'m left'
        },
        'right@splitscreen': {
            template: 'I\'m right'
        }
    }
});
```

The problem is that clicking on tabs reloads the entire `'splitscreen'` state. I want to update only the contents of the `'left'` and `'right'` views. How can I do this?

I tried setting `reloadOnSearch: false` in the `'splitscreen'` configuration, but then my tabs become not clickable at all.

Here's a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/7LZFAxerHoNmFA0j3ywE).

Comment: [plnkr.co](http://plnkr.co/) is down at the moment...

Comment: @MichaelP. it's back ;P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, it seems that ui-router is unable to do what I wanted. Too bad.

I've temporarily solved it with:

```
<a
 ng-click="setTab('1')"
 ng-class="'tab' + (getTab() === '1' ? '--selected' : '')">
    Tab 1
</a>
<a
 ng-click="setTab('2')"
 ng-class="'tab' + (getTab() === '2' ? '--selected' : '')">
    Tab 2
</a>

<div ng-include="getTabUrl()"></div>
```

Where the functions are defined as:

```
$scope.setTab = function (tabName) {
    $location.search('tab', tabName);
};

$scope.getTab = function (tabName) {
    return $location.search().tab;
};

$scope.getTabUrl = function () {
    return 'foo/' + $scope.getTab() + '.tpl.html';
};
```

And the state has the following options:

```
url: '/foo?tab',
reloadOnSearch: false
```